# Search engine that allows results to be scraped?

Tags: screen-scraping, search-engine

Since site scraping Google, Bing, etc. is against their terms of service I was wondering if there is any search engine that allows results to be scraped?

Answer (score 2):

Why scrape? Why not use the supported APIs?

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

http://www.bing.com/developers

http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html

Comment: Google only allows 100 queries per day so it's totally pointless. Yahoo API is limited as well. I'll have to check out Bing, but I just read the Yahoo TOS and they don't seem to prohibit scraping so they might be the way to go (although they are powered by Bing, so IDK). Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: The Google Search API is totally inaccurate as well, and doesn't match the real results. If they really gave you accurate results, SEO's would have a field day, and Google would be gamed even more.

Answer (score 0):

You might be actually looking for [Google JSON Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html): it allows you to legitimately search Google from your program, and is easier to use than screen-scraping.

Comment: Same problems with the JSON API as pointed above: a uselessly low daily limit, and doesn't match actual Google results from a national google site.

Comment: Also now deprecated, in favor of the (extremely expensive) custom search API.